# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' - Firebase integration with Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter, androidx

I am trying to integrate Firebase into my existing Flutter application. Before integrating, I have migrated my project to AndroidX from Android Studio. I have done the steps mentioned in the official guide to integrate Firebase into Flutter. When I run the app, it is giving me the error:

> - Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "E:\My Projects\MyProject\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'E:\My Projects\MyProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > ASCII
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 8s   Command: E:\My
>   Projects\MyProject\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
>
> Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

I searched about this error and found some answers instructing to switch to `com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0` from `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2`. Did that and got this error:

> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
>   is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

Searched about this, saw that `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0` fixes this problem. So I used it in `build.gradle` and this is what I got:

> - Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "E:\My Projects\MyProject\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'E:\My Projects\MyProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > ASCII
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s   Command: E:\My
>   Projects\MyProject\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
>
> Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Nothing seems to work for me. Please find below the contents of the gradle files.

**android/gradle.properties:**

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

**android/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle:**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.buy_io"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_money_formatter: ^0.8.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Muli
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Muli-ExtraLight.ttf
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: I've been able to fix this by resetting my Flutter installation. Also, use latest version of Kotlin in the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action here would be to try removing the Firebase SDK that you've set up and see if the Flutter project builds. Then try setting up Firebase using `flutterfire configure`. You may follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) from the docs for more details.